# Nil when passsing data back to another ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

tell me, please, why am I getting nil? I have 2 controllers: `MainViewController` and `MililetersViewController`.
In the `MainViewController`, the user clicks on the button and enters the `MililetersViewController`, where he selects the volume of the drink in `PickerView`. Further, on the same View, the user clicks on the "Add" button and the data selected by the user should go back to the `MainViewController` and write to `label.text`

`MainViewController` code:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, MililetersVCDelegate {
    var selectedVolume = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var resultValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentValue: UILabel!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Main"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.resultValue.text = UserSettings.result
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }

      @IBAction func unwindToMainVC(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {}

    func passingDataBack(withString: String) {
        self.currentValue.text = withString
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as? MililetersViewController
        vc?.proto = self 
    }

}
```

`MililetersViewConrtoller` code:

```
import UIKit

protocol MililetersVCDelegate {
    func passingDataBack(withString: String)
}

class MililetersViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerViewOutlet: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButtonOutlet: UIButton!

    var selectedVolume = ""
    var volume = MilimetersScreen()
    var proto: MililetersVCDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerViewOutlet.dataSource = self
        pickerViewOutlet.delegate = self
        self.transitioningDelegate = self

    }


    @IBAction func goToMainVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        proto.passingDataBack(withString: selectedVolume) // ERROR: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

        performSegue(withIdentifier: K.BackToMainView, sender: self)
    }
  }

extension MililetersViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
             return 1
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return volume.volumeArray.count
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return String(volume.volumeArray[row]) + " " + "ml"
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            selectedVolume = String(volume.volumeArray[row])
            print(selectedVolume) // Here I see that the number from the array and pickerView are written into the variable
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 35
        }

    }
```

Here I get the error that there is nil:

```
@IBAction func goToMainVC (_ sender: UIButton) {
            proto.passingDataBack (withString: selectedVolume) // ERROR: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

            performSegue (withIdentifier: K.BackToMainView, sender: self)
        }
      }
```

I don't understand where nil is. Please, help

Comment: Did you make sure `proto` is getting set from `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: Can you please check you have mapped all your IBOutlet objects? I tried running your code and it's working for me.

Comment: I wrote `print (vc?.proto)` in `prepareForSegue` and got `nil`. But how can I then pass data back to the `MainViewController`? Sorry, I'm just a beginner and I don’t understand all the aspects yet

Comment: `IBOutlet`s are all code related

Comment: @Kenton What do you mean by IBOutlet's are all code related?

Comment: If you are getting nil by `print (vc?.proto)` in `prepareForSegue` then destination for your segue must not pointing to `MililetersViewController ` in storyboard. can you check this?
make sure you have not embedded `MililetersViewController` in navigation controller or any other type of parent controller?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable for `selectedRow`

You can access with `pickerViewOutlet.selectedRow(inComponent: .zero)`

and be sure your segues